# Run tool via Python in cmd does not wait

Tags: python, windows, process, cmd, subprocess

I'm running a tool via `Python` in `cmd`. For each sample in a given directory I want that tool to do something. However, when I use `process = subprocess.Popen(command)` in the loop, the commands does not wait untill its finished, resulting in 10 prompts at once. And when I use `subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)` the command remains black and I can't see the progress, although it does wait untill the command is finished.

Does anyone know a way how to call an external tool via `Python` in `cmd`, that does wait untill the command is finished and thats able to show the progress of the tool in the `cmd`?

```
#main.py
        for sample in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
            if ".fastq" in sample and '_R1_' in sample and "Temp" not in sample:
                print time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
                DNA_Bowtie2.DNA_Bowtie2(os.getcwd()+'\\'+sample+'\\'+sample)

#DNA_Bowtie2.py
            # Run Bowtie2 command and wait for process to be finished.
            process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
            process.wait()
            process.stdout.read()
```

Edit: command = a perl or java command. With above make-up I cannot see tool output since the prompt (perl window, or java window) remains black.

Comment: `process.communicate()` should wait for the process to finish.

Comment: This resulted in atleast 10 processes (there are also 10 samples in the directory). Instead of 1 by 1. So that did not work.            process = subprocess.Popen(command) process.communicate()

Comment: So you want it to block, then wait() should be the way to go. No idea why it won't work for you though. Have you tried using `subprocess.call(command)`

Comment: I am able to block the processes untill they are finished. (process.wait()). But with the current make-up I can't see the tools output, all I see is a black screen. And when I just apply (subprocess.Popen(command)), I dó see the output, but then again process.wait() does not work.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your subprocess forks otherwise there is no way the wait() would return before the process has finished.

Comment: I am able to block the processes untill they are finished. (process.wait()). But with the current make-up I can't see the tools output, all I see is a black screen. And when I just apply (subprocess.Popen(command)), I dó see the output, but then again process.wait() does not work.

Comment: I seem not to get your problem. I any order of read()/wait() there will be no concurrency. Just that wait()/read() won't work. Except of course you run concurrency in your program.

Answer (score 0):

The order is important here: first read the output, then wait.

If you do it this way:

```
process.wait()
process.stdout.read()
```

you can experience a deadlock if the pipe buffer is completely full: the subprocess blocks on waiting on stdout and never reaches the end, your program blocks on `wait()` and never reaches the `read()`.

Do instead

```
process.stdout.read()
process.wait()
```

which will read until EOF.

This holds for if you want the stdout of the process at all.

If you don't want that, you should omit the `stdout=PIPE` stuff. Then the output is directed into that prompt window. Then you can omit `process.stdout.read()` as well.

Normally, the `process.wait()` should then prevent that 10 instances run at once. If that doesn't work, I don't know why not...

Comment: This works, the only thing is that when applying that for process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE) a Java prompt shows that does not show process. The prompt stays black, and closes when the process is finished. I still can't see output.

Comment: @user3589561 I extended my answer.